# awk interpolation of values in column

Tags: text-processing, awk

i'm facing a problem with looong txt files i have this exemple :

```
542    701.00
789    
971    703.00
123    708.00
879    
785    
974
101    716.00
```

and i need to replace the missed values in column $2 with interpolated values between the top and bottom values near the missed values , i did try nothing because i realy have no idea how to  even start! so can smeone help me here ? thanks

OUtPUT

```
542    701.00
789    702.00
971    703.00
123    708.00
879    710.00
785    712.00
974    714.00
101    716.00
```

Comment: Add the expected output to your question.

Comment: **Interpolate (v): insert (something of a different nature) into something else.**  This tells us absolutely nothing about what your desired output should be.

Comment: the output is clear i just want to replace missed values with interpolated values for ex: the frst missed value is clear that equal to 702.00

Comment: Two people now are telling you that it is not clear so it, in fact, **is not** clear.  How about the next missing values?  Should it be 709, 710, 711 or 713, 715, 716?  Or should it be grape, apple, banana?

Comment: a linear interpolation between the top and bottom !!!

Comment: Okay but your second missing block is 3 numbers but the values are 708-716 which is 8 values.  How should that be handled?

Comment: the 3 values in that case must be 710 712 714

Comment: @jesse_b, I don't know where you found your definition of "to interpolate", I would never have thought about inserting something of a "different nature".   Perhaps have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille: Oxford dictionary

Comment: awk isn't a good tool for this. You should use statistics tools like R or python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the interpolated values should be just spaced at equal intervals, then this may do:

```
awk '
  NF > 1 {
    if(i++){ d=($2-s)/i; for(j=1; j<i; j++) printf "%s\t%.2f\n", a[j], s+j*d }
    s=$2; i=0; printf "%s\t%.2f\n", $1, $2
    next
  }
  { a[++i] = $1 }
' file
```

And no, this is not the only way to "interpolate".

Comment: is there another way !!! , thank you so much by the way for your time sir

Comment: The OP has been very stingy with information, and, in fact, has said absolutely nothing about the values in the first column.  The only thing we know for sure is that they *aren't* sorted numbers. So it might be safer if you displayed them with ``%s`` instead of ``%g``.

Comment: @Scott done, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
  BEGIN {split("",A)}
  $2 == "" {
    A[length(A)] = $1
    # print $0, length(A)
  }
  $2 != "" {
    if (length(A) > 0) {
      I = ( $2 - P2 ) / (length(A) + 1)
      for(X=0; X<length(A); X++) {
        print "<" A[X] " "  (P2 + I * (X+1)) ">"
      }
      split("",A)
    }
    print  "!" $1 " " $2 "!"
    P1=$1; P2=$2
  }
  END {}
'
```

gives

```
!542 701.00!
<789 702>
!971 703.00!
!123 708.00!
<879 710>
<785 712>
<974 714>
!101 716.00!
```

Comment: why ! and <> can you delete them and print values with two decimals

Comment: Don't you know how to do that?